# Angular Material tab grayed out even on the active tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material tabs. The behavior by default is to have the tab label be slightly grayed out. If you click on a tab, the label will remove the opacity until you click on another tab or somewhere else on the screen. Even though this is how it works by default, is there a way to override this by removing any opacity on the active tab, no matter what else you are doing?

Comment: You need to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about the focus indicator - I recommend you leave that alone.

Comment: Nathaniel Johnson, you can see the behavior on Angular Material's site. The examples behave in this manner. https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the parent component's CSS

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label.mat-tab-label-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Note** ::ng-deep won't work in the global styles page

Comment: Thanks Mendy! I placed this in my styles.css without the ::ng-deep and works perfectly.